# Plotting differences with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidytext

I have an R dataframe (named `frequency`) like this:

```
word    author  proportion
a   Radicals    1.679437e-04
aa  Radicals    2.099297e-04
aaa Radicals    2.099297e-05
abbe    Radicals    NA
aboow   Radicals    NA
about   Radicals    NA
abraos  Radicals    NA
ytterst Conservatives   5.581042e-06
yttersta    Conservatives   5.581042e-06
yttra   Conservatives   2.232417e-05
yttrandefrihet  Conservatives   5.581042e-06
yttrar  Conservatives   2.232417e-05
```

I want to plot document differences using ggplot2. Something like [this](http://tidytextmining.com/01-tidy-text_files/figure-html/plotcompare-1.png)

I have the code below, but my plot ends up empty.

```
library(scales)
ggplot(frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = `Radicals`, color = abs(`Radicals` - proportion))) +
    geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
    geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
    geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
  facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  labs(y = "Radicals", x = NULL)
```

Comment: `y = Radicals` is not correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are wanting to do is make a plot comparing the frequency of one "author" (like, say, Conservatives) on the x-axis and one "author" (perhaps the Radicals) on the y-axis, you need to `spread` your dataframe (from the tidyr package) so that you can plot it that way.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

frequency %>%
  spread(author, proportion) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Conservatives, Radicals)) +
  geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
  scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format())
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve it like [this](https://github.com/simonlindgren/Tidy-Text-comparisons/blob/master/Tidy%2Btext%2Bcomparisons.ipynb). Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Yep, it looks like it; you might think about trying out `spread()` next time instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your plot ends up empty because there isn't a column 'Radicals'.  if you're trying to narrow to only Radicals and then plot that you should do something like

```
 radical_frequecy <- subset(frequency, author == 'Radicals')
```

then you can do

```
 library(scales)
 ggplot(radical_frequency, aes(x = proportion, y = author, color = abs(`Radicals` - proportion))) +
geom_abline(color = "gray40", lty = 2) +
geom_jitter(alpha = 0.1, size = 2.5, width = 0.3, height = 0.3) +
geom_text(aes(label = word), check_overlap = TRUE, vjust = 1.5) +
   scale_x_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
   scale_y_log10(labels = percent_format()) +
   scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, 0.001), low = "darkslategray4", high = "gray75") +
   theme(legend.position="none") +
   labs(y = "Radicals", x = NULL)
```

(I took out facet wrap since you've already narrowed to Radicals. You could add that back in and *then* do the first bit of code if you did y=author and facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2)

basically, tl:dr your error is caused by trying to create an axis from a variable not a column

Comment: Still same problem. I try to follow the tutorial for [Figure 1.3 here](http://tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html#fig:plotcompare)

Comment: ok, well again, it looks like you missed the core step at the top where they created the mutated data frame.  I think you might go back and try those steps.

Comment: then your frequency table does not reflect that.  the output from the example would have a column for each author there. yours does not. look up how ggplot works for these kind of plots and you'll better be able to make these kinds of charts.  there's tons of great tutorials such as [this one](http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-Tutorial-With-R.html)